# Delete element with ajax in django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am currently having some issue in deleting element with ajax in a Django Application.
I have some pictures, each of them displayed in a bootstrap card.
Basically, my code is kind of working, but I couldn't figure out why, for example, when I display the pictures in the card, in the first one of the list the Delete button doesn't work and, when I have multiple pictures, the delete button works but delete the first picture on the list and not the right one.
I may have some mistake in fetching the IDs, but so far I couldn't find where the issue is.
I post some code

views.py

```
def delete_uploaded_picture(request, pk):
picture = Picture.objects.get(id=pk)
if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
    picture.delete()
    return JsonResponse({})
```

js

```
const deleteForms = document.getElementsByClassName('delete_form')
deleteForms.forEach(deleteForm => deleteForm.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
let pk = deleteForm.getAttribute('data-pk')
const cardDiv = document.getElementById('card_div'+pk)
const clickedBtn = document.getElementById('clicked_btn'+pk)
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: $("#my-url-div").data('url'),
    data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        'pk': pk,
    }, 
    success: function(response){
        $('#card_div'+pk).hide();
        handleAlerts('success', 'Immagine Rimossa')
    }, 
    error: function(error){
        handleAlerts('danger', 'Ops qualcosa è andato storto!')
    }
})
}))
```

html

```
<div class="form-group mt-2">
                    <div class="row">
                    {% if question.picture_set.all %}
                        {% for pic in question.picture_set.all %}
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" id="card_div{{pic.id}}">
                            <form action="" method="post" class="delete_form" data-pk="{{pic.id}}">
                                <div class="card picture_card" id="my-url-div" data-url="{% url 'main:delete_uploaded_picture' pk=pic.id %}">
                                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ pic.picture.url }}" alt="">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete_picture" id="clicked_btn{{pic.id}}">Elimina</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I inspected the html and the IDs are right in the card, so it's something else.

Comment: try to debug in Function. print ids in django view and see if its correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should change this line:

```js
let pk = deleteForm.getAttribute('data-pk');
```

To:

```js
let pk = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-pk');
```

Generally in function are you querying objects using className, so it returns multiple object and overrides only one. In `e.currentTarget` you have element that you clicked, so it does not select it via random way.

Basically I am not sure if the forloop assign is working correctly, the javascript does it own magic in forloops (for example - it makes them asynchrous) so I would not be suprised it does not work as expected and the value you are getting into `pk` is not that you want.

Answer (score 0):

// Delete Data

```
$("tbody").on("click", ".btn-del", function () {
    //console.log("Delete Button Clicked");
    let id = $(this).attr("data-sid");
    let csr = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken").val();
    //console.log(id);
    mydata = { sid: id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csr };
    mythis = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'delete' %}",
        method: "POST",
        data: mydata,
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            if (data.status == 1) {
                $("#msg").text("Data Deleted Successfully");
                $("#msg").show();
                $(mythis).closest("tr").fadeOut();
            }
            if (data.status == 0) {
                $("#msg").text("Unable to Delete Data");
                $("#msg").show();
            }
        },
    });
});
```

========= Output ==============

[image]

Comment: Yeah but this actually doesn't reply to my question. I may have some error in my code. This is just another code of a table that doesn't have anything in common. Anyway, in the meantime I try do adjust mine one...